# snowbabel extension translation bug

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I've a problem with Snowbabel extension. I am using the typo3 version 4.7.2 and Snowbabel 3.6.1.
My default language is deutsch and an English language also.
I am trying to translate the extension sr_feuser_register using snowbabel.
When I add translation for deutsch content its working fine.
But the problem with English translation. In english translation, the sr_feuser_register extension shows the
default English text from the locallang file and not the translated text using snowbabel.

I need to change the default english language labels using snowbabel.

Is it possible ? In the manual I saw that we can't edit the default text using snowbabel.
If the question is unclear please inform me.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do we have separate arrays for default and english language labels?

Comment: No.There is only one array for dafault language labels.

Answer (score 1):

Snowbabel is not touching original labels in extensions. So it's not created for edit the default-Language.

It is using the "l10n"-mecanism from TYPO3. So xml or xliff files will be created in typo3conf/l10n/{langKey}/{myext}/../{langKey}.locallang.xml for example.

But your Problem is located here:
http://forge.typo3.org/issues/42084

Since typo3 always change 'en' to 'default' files in typo3conf/l10n/en/ will not work anymore.
As long as this issue is not solved in typo3 core, the system will not recognize your 'en' translations in typo3conf/l10n/

in the meantime use Typoscript or overwrite the whole translation file with a hook.

Comment: [Latest TYPO3 releases](http://typo3.org/news/article/typo3-cms-4523-4616-478-and-602-released/) including a patch taking care of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use a separate array for English language labels as you have already told that it's not possible to modify the default language labels (typo3conf/l10n/en/sr_feuser_register/en.locallang.xml or in the extension locallang.xml file itself) ?

I think using typoscript language configuration you can fetch those English language labels for default language.

Comment: Yes.When adding typoscript configurations its working fine.But the user cannot managed it. They want to use the snowbabel extension.

Comment: Can't we use a separate array for English language labels? I meant about "typoscript language configuration" and not about "typoscript to override locallang.xml values".